# Avoid Jquery Plugin Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

on the same page i'm using this plugin:

```
$g=jQuery.noConflict();
$g(function() {
    /*
    number of fieldsets
    */
    var fieldsetCount = $g('#formElem').children().length;

    /*
    current position of fieldset / navigation link
    */
    var current     = 1;

    /*
    sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets
    set the final sum as the total width of the steps element
    */
    var stepsWidth  = 0;
    var widths      = new Array();
    $g('#steps .step').each(function(i){
        var $step       = $g(this);
        widths[i]       = stepsWidth;
        stepsWidth      += $step.width();
    });
    $g('#steps').width(stepsWidth);

    /*
    to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form
    */
    $g('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus();    

    /*
    show the navigation bar
    */
    $g('#navigation_form').show();

    /*
    when clicking on a navigation link 
    the form slides to the corresponding fieldset
    */
    $g('#navigation_form a').bind('click',function(e){
        var $this   = $g(this);
        var prev    = current;
        $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $this.parent().addClass('selected');
        /*
        we store the position of the link
        in the current variable 
        */
        current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
        /*
        animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
        fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
        is the order of the fieldsets.
        Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
        input element of the new fieldset
        If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
        all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
        before the form slided
        */
        $g('#steps').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + widths[current-1] + 'px'
        },500,function(){
            if(current == fieldsetCount)
                validateSteps();
            else
                validateStep(prev);
            $g('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus();   
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /*
    clicking on the tab (on the last input of each fieldset), makes the form
    slide to the next step
    */
    $g('#formElem > fieldset').each(function(){
        var $fieldset = $g(this);
        $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){
            if (e.which == 9){
                $g('#navigation_form li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();
                /* force the blur for validation */
                $g(this).blur();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    /*
    validates errors on all the fieldsets
    records if the Form has errors in $('#formElem').data()
    */
    function validateSteps(){
        var FormErrors = false;
        for(var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i){
            var error = validateStep(i);
            if(error == -1)
                FormErrors = true;
        }
        $g('#formElem').data('errors',FormErrors);  
    }

    /*
    validates one fieldset
    and returns -1 if errors found, or 1 if not
    */
    function validateStep(step){
        if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

        var error = 1;
        var hasError = false;
        $g('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
            var $this       = $g(this);
            var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

            if(valueLength == ''){
                hasError = true;
                $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
            }
            else
                $this.css('background-color','#FFFFFF');    
        });
        var $link = $g('#navigation_form li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
        $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

        var valclass = 'checked';
        if(hasError){
            error = -1;
            valclass = 'error';
        }
        $g('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);

        return error;
    }

    /*
    if there are errors don't allow the user to submit
    */
    $g('#registerButton').bind('click',function(){
        if($g('#formElem').data('errors')){
            alert('Please correct the errors in the Form');
            return false;
        }   
    });
});
```

and this one:

```
 (function($){

 $countCursos = 1;
 $countFormsA = 1;
 $countFormsB = 1;

      $.fn.addForms = function(idform){

                    var adicionar_curso = "<p>"+
                     "  <label for='nome_curso'>Nome do Curso</label>"+
                     "  <input id='nome_curso' name='nome_curso["+$countCursos+"]' type='text' />"+
                     "  </p>";


    var myform2 = "<table>"+
                     "  <tr>"+
                     "     <td>Field C</td>"+
                     "     <td><input type='text' name='fieldc["+$countFormsA+"]'></td>"+
                     "     <td>Field D ("+$countFormsA+"):</td>"+
                     "     <td><textarea name='fieldd["+$countFormsA+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                     "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                     "  </tr>"+
                     "</table>";

    var myform3 = "<table>"+
                     "  <tr>"+
                     "     <td>Field C</td>"+
                     "     <td><input type='text' name='fieldc["+$countFormsB+"]'></td>"+
                     "     <td>Field D ("+$countFormsB+"):</td>"+
                     "     <td><textarea name='fieldd["+$countFormsB+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                     "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                     "  </tr>"+
                     "</table>";


                    if(idform=='novo_curso'){
                        alert(idform);
                        adicionar_curso = $("<div>"+adicionar_curso+"</div>");
                        $("button", $(adicionar_curso)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
                        $(this).append(adicionar_curso);
                        $countCursos++;
                    }


                        if(idform=='mybutton1'){
                        alert(idform);
                        myform2 = $("<div>"+myform2+"</div>");
                        $("button", $(myform2)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
                        $(this).append(myform2);

                            $countFormsA++;

                        }

                    if(idform=='mybutton2'){
                        alert(idform);
                        myform3 = $("<div>"+myform3+"</div>");
                        $("button", $(myform3)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
                        $(this).append(myform3);

                            $countFormsB++;

                        }





      };
})(jQuery);         

 $(function(){
    $("#mybutton1").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idform=this.id;

        if($countFormsA<3){
            $("#container1").addForms(idform);
        }       
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("#novo_curso").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idform=this.id;
    alert(idform);
        if($countCursos<3){
            $("#outro_curso").addForms(idform);
        }       
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("#mybutton2").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idform=this.id;

        if($countFormsB<3){
            $("#container2").addForms(idform);
        }       
    });
});
```

My problem is the two are making conflict:

I added previously the $g on the first to avoid conflict, but the truth is they don't work together, any hint how can i configure the second one to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

well, on the same page i want to run this other jquery file:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(function() {
    $j('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $j('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-55px'  /* para não elevar muito o separador*/
                }, 300);
            $j('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'-10px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $j('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-130px'  /* para baixar o separador para o sitio original*/
                }, 300);
            $j('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'50px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );
});
```

it does conflict :/
its a jquerycore?

Comment: Since they are both using jQuery, you shouldn't need noConflict. Are you including jQuery.js more than once?

Comment: No, i just call him once on the head:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In that case definitely remove noConflict (unless you are using some other library that makes use of the `$` variable. What errors are happening and on what code?

Comment: Thanks, i removed noConflict and now it's working :P
But what if need to add other jquery files? Won't they be in conflict?

Comment: If it is another jquerycore.js, yes it will conflict, but you really should never *have* to include another jquerycore.js. It is usually better to make the plugin compatible with whatever version of jquerycore.js you are using.

Comment: just a last problem. i added a thir jquery file to the page, (its the third piece of code in the question above), it does conflict :/
it's a jquery core?

Comment: i already tried removing the part of the nonConflic but still doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: the third piece shouldn't cause a conflict unless it is including it's own version of jquery.

Comment: i don't know why, but i can't run the last plugin i added without the noConflict();
just notice now, even without the other two, this one don't run correctly without the noConflict() part :/ any hint?

Comment: if you remove the noConflict, you must replace $j with $ or jQuery